# Date format in Talend "2006-05-27 17:00:00.000"

Tags: date, talend

I am facing an issue with Talend dates. I have tried several solutions but still an "unparseable date" error persists.

My date format is of the form : "2006-05-27 17:00:00.000"
 Can you help me ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601
YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.sss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't handle the conversion yourself in a **tMap** but just want to use a schema, then: In your mapping configuration in the date field, you can add the following string:

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS
```

to set the correct format mapping for the date string. Otherwise the answer of garpitmzn is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

you can use below talendDate function to parse your string into date..

TalendDate.parseDate("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.sss","2006-05-27 17:00:00.000")

this would take input as string and return you date.

Comment: Millisecond parsing uses uppercase `SSS` ([see API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)).

Answer (score 0):

you should use this function in talend to fetch date: 
TalendDate.parseDate("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS","2016-01-12 12:45:00.000")